# Display array in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, cycle

Please tell me how can I display array in a for loop in php? 
I have this array:

```
while($q = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectQuestResult)) {    
   $answers[] = array(array($q['name']),array(round($total,1)));}
```

then I want display it:

Comment: Please check for each loop or while loop in net

Comment: sorru, but I must use for

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Show some sample code

Comment: then I want dispaly it for($i = 0;$i<count($answers[0]);$i++){
echo $answers[0][$i];
}

Comment: Edit your question to include the code you've tried, reading code in the comments is unnecessary hard.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($answers); $i++)
{
    echo($answers[$i][0][0].':'.$answers[$i][1][0]."<br />\n");
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

*I must use a for loop* makes this sound like stupid college professor tricks. But, that's ok.  for loops can have break statements in them. And, they don't have to contain end conditions in the for statement.

```
 for( $i = 0; ; $i++) {
    $q = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectQuestResult);
    if (!$q) break;
    $answers[] = array($q['name'], round( $total, 1));
 }
 for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $answers ), $i++) {
       /* do something with $answers[i] */
 }
```